# Generate a list of 2,000 users with realistic information

Tags: php, database, loops, ldap

## Context

I installed a LDAP directory to implement SSO with our products and assess the performance.

I used PHP to create 2,000 generic users like `mister1`, `mister2`, `...`, `mister2000`.

Now the next step is with realistic information like `Bob Mclow`, `Steve Blop` and 1998 others.

Obviously it should not be any duplication.

## Question

Do you know a method to create a large amount of fake users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a service like :
http://www.generatedata.com/#generator

you can define the fields here , and export your data as a file.
Import that in PHP to populate your ldap directory.

P.S. - It is also available to download and run it on your own server.

http://www.generatedata.com/#download

Answer (score 1):

[SLAMD](http://www.slamd.com) provides a template-based LDIF generator called makeldif that can be useful.